# how to print a loop output in a table format using python

Tags: python, printing, format

My script is working but I have not been able to print output in a table format. I have two files - I read file1 sequences and see if any of them binds with any sequence in file2.

file1.fa

```
>seq1
ACCGG
>seq2
AATTTC
```

file2.fa

```
>seq3
CCGGT
>seq9
GGGGGGCCC
```

current output:

```
---
file1.seq
>seq1
ACCGG
file2.seq
>seq3
CCGGT
```

Based on the files only `seq1` binds with `seq3` and the current output based on my code is correct but then I have to get the output I want in a format showing every sequence ids against each other - marked with 1 if they interact and marked with 0 if they do not.

I need help to fix the `print` part to get output in a table format as below:

```
    file2   seq3   seq9
file1 

seq1          1         0

seq2          0         0
```

My code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Seq import Seq

records=list(SeqIO.parse("file1.fa","fasta"))

window_size = 5
step_size = 1

target_records=list(SeqIO.parse("file2.fa","fasta"))

for i in records:
    for j in range(0, len(i.seq)-window_size+1):
        for k in (i.seq.reverse_complement()[j: j+5].split()):
            for l in target_records:
                if l.seq.find(k)!=-1:
                    print('---\n{}\n>{}\n{}\n{}\n>{}\n{}'.format ("file1.seq", i.id,i.seq, "file2.seq", l.id,l.seq))
```

Thank you

Comment: This is not really something to "fix", you just need to write more/different code. What exactly was the difficulty?

Comment: I could not manage the print part in order to get the table format.

Comment: I tried to search for a way to print the output in a table format but I am not that professional in programming so it would be great if you could give me some help - Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd like to uses pandas when i want get the table format:
for example:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import pandas as pd


def same_seq(a_record, brecord):
    window_size = 5
    step_size = 1
    for j in range(0, len(a_record.seq) - window_size + 1):
        for k in (a_record.seq.reverse_complement()[j: j + 5].split()):
            return brecord.seq.find(k) != -1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    records = list(SeqIO.parse("file1.fa", "fasta"))
    target_records = list(SeqIO.parse("file2.fa", "fasta"))
    rows_list = []
    for target_record in target_records:
        new_row = {'name': target_record.name}
        for record in records:
            if same_seq(record, target_record):
                new_row[record.name] = 1
            else:
                new_row[record.name] = 0
        rows_list.append(new_row)
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)
    df = df.set_index(["name"])
    print(df)
```

```
      seq1  seq2
name            
seq3     1     0
seq9     0     0
```

if you wana change the compare of seq:
you should use `seq[j: j+5].reverse_complement()` but `seq.reverse_complement()[j: j+5]`
I'm not sure if I understand it right
`file1.fa`

```
>seq1
ACCGG
>seq2
AATTTC
>seqtest1
NNNACCGTGCNN
```

`file1.fa`

```
>seq1
ACCGG
>seq2
AATTTC
>seqtest1
NNNACCGTGCNN
```

`file2.fa`

```
>seq3
CCGGT
>seq9
GGGGGGCCC
>seqtest2
NNCACGGTNN
```

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import pandas as pd



def same_seq_window(a_record, b_record, window_size):
    for i in range(len(a_record.seq)- window_size + 1):
        a_seq = a_record.seq[i: i + window_size]
        if b_record.seq.find(a_seq.reverse_complement()) != -1:
            return True
    return False

def same_seq(a_record, b_record):
    window_sizes = range(5, len(a_record.seq)+1)
    for window_size in window_sizes:
        if same_seq_window(a_record, b_record, window_size):
            return True
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    records = list(SeqIO.parse("file1.fa", "fasta"))
    target_records = list(SeqIO.parse("file2.fa", "fasta"))
    rows_list = []
    for target_record in target_records:
        new_row = {'name': target_record.name}
        for record in records:
            if same_seq(record, target_record):
                new_row[record.name] = 1
            else:
                new_row[record.name] = 0
        rows_list.append(new_row)
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)
    df = df.set_index(["name"])
    print(df)
```

```
          seq1  seq2  seqtest1
name                          
seq3         1     0         0
seq9         0     0         0
seqtest2     0     0         1
```

Comment: Thank you @Para for your help - I really needed it. I have a very small problem remaining - I tried the code with two new dummy sequences (each from a different file) and tried to capture windows size equal to 6 but then the code did not report the two sequences that binds. Below I put the sequences

Comment: seq1 ```NNNACCGTGCNN```  if we consider the ```ACCGTG``` window of the sequence it can match with ```CACGGT``` in seq2 sequence ```NNCACGGTNN```.  The reverse complement of the ```ACCGTG``` (from seq1) is ```CACGGT``` which is inside the seq2 sequence then these two should be reported in the table.

Comment: basically, every window with a length equal to 6 should be considered - so for a dummy sequence with length 7 there should be two windows with length equal to 6. for example ACGTACG has two windows with size 6 as ```ACGTAC``` and ```CGTACG```

Comment: every window  from file1 should be searched inside all sequences of file 2

Comment: @mkrieger1 is right.Generally speaking, you should write these things yourself, because you already know how to write them.Just like when I google it, I know what reverse_complement means,i changed the Answer